# Undocumented flag in CC

Tags: aix, cc, unix-ar

When compiling a file using a new version of Informix-4GL it launches the following command link the generated object into a executable.

```
cc -qchars=signed -D_H_LOCALEDEF -DASIAN -DAIX_43 -DAIX_53 -DUSE_PROTOTYPES \ 
   -Dsigflag=ix_os_sigflag -DTERMINFO -bh:8 -s -brtl -DASIAN \
   -qarch=com -qchars=signed -D_H_LOCALEDEF -DINFX_ANSI -DASIAN \
   -s -DAIX_43 -DAIX_53 \
   -o teste -s teste.o \
   -lm -lbsd -lc_r -ldl -ltli_r -lm_r
```

If there are an undefined symbol, it gives an error, but generates the file `teste`, although without execution permission. This behaviour is different from the previous versions and it does not go well with make: if I do make 2 times, the first time it gives the undef error, but in the second time it does nothing, because the executable already exists.

If I take out the `-bh:8` option, it works as before (does not generate the exec file).

Does anyone knows this option/flag: `-bh:8` ? I could not find it in the cc documentaion.

Answer (score 1):

I believe `-bh` is short for `-bhalt`, which specifies the maximum error level that is allowed before the linker command halts.